# ACPI BIOS error on HP laptop

Tags: boot, acpi

hey im extremely new to Ubuntu and have only been using Linux overall for 6 months. Whenever I boot my laptop I'm greeted with this instead of it just loading regularly.
Not to look stupid but I was just hoping someone could help me figure out what the cause of this would be and or how to fix it. Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on an HP laptop 14-dk1018ca

````
CH5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[0.295252] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/ps
object-220)
[
1.565450] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
/dev/nvmeon1p2: clean, 443148/15597568 files, 14840269/62383360 blocks```
````

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It will help people who want to answer your question if you edit your post and add details about your Ubuntu version.

Comment: To be clear: does your laptop not start up at all, or does it start up normally after showing these messages? Is your laptop very new? These messages have been seen on very new systems. After a while, a new kernel update was installed and the messages went away. So if your system does start up properly, the messages may be completely harmless.

Comment: No it starts up! And it is just over 3 years old I got it in about 2020, I was just wasn't sure if this was something I should be concerned about or not. the only disadvantage of it is that it's annoying lol but that's that

Comment: See this question & answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/acpi-bios-error-ae-not-found